# Finding the number of cyclic isomers algorithmically

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

Is there an algorithm for finding the number of cyclic isomers a given compound might have?

I've found a general algorithm for all isomers: [link](http://www-jmg.ch.cam.ac.uk/data/isomercount/isojava.html), but I'm not sure how to apply it for cyclic isomers only.

Comment: Do you care only for structural isomers, or do you need spatial isomers too? I'm sure including the latter makes it a much harder problem.

Comment: Only structural isomers.

Comment: I wouldn't be astonished if A. T. Balaban has published something on this. Apart from his great book on pyrylium salts, he has spent decades on the application of graph theory in chemistry.

Comment: Wow, that code listed is awful. It really hurts my eyes!

Comment: Depending on the level of complexity, you may want to consider statistical approaches (treating isomers as populations) too.

Comment: You can form a cyclic isomer many times, though unstable. For ex. the cyclo-propane is highly unstable because of ring strain. How would an algorithm take care of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly, several years ago I stumbled over the SMOG program addressing this question ([description here](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ci950393z)).  The software requestested sum formula and a selection of allowed structural elements, cyclic substructures were among them.  Maybe the algorithms implemented are not the first ones to answer such a question, yet publications like [this](http://www.jcheminf.com/content/4/1/21) showcase continuing interest in this field, too.