# Number of geometrical isomers

Tags: organic-chemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

How do I find out the total no of geometrical and stereo isomers of the compound given as $\ce{C2FClBrI}$? Is there any way I can list out all the possible structures mathematically without having to think about each structure in my mind? Any suggestion how you would do it would be wonderful.

Comment: Well, do you know what geometry this type of compounds has - you need  to know symmetry of compound.

Comment: No but id love to know the more general way to deal with having to tell the total number of isomers of any type of compound

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7975/finding-the-number-of-cyclic-isomers-algorithmically?rq=1 http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/how-to-determine-number-of-structural-isomers http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33356/is-there-a-formula-to-determine-the-total-number-of-constitutional-isomers

Comment: FC(I)=C(Cl)Br,
FC(Br)=C(Cl)I,
FC(Cl)=C(Br)I